# How can I pass in form type data to a form HOC when the structure can change on each form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, typescript

I have a HOC address form that I prefil with `myData`. The `formData` has type information specific to Addresses (eg. `Address: string, apartment: number ...`}

```
<AddressForm formData={myData}/>
```

But when I build a login form the fields will have a different data structure (eg `email: string, password: string ...`)

How can I type my data if the data will change from form to form?

If I type the data object to any, then I lose any advantage of typescript.

Comment: Can you provide some example code of how you're composing your form?

Comment: And also provide how you are handling your types at the moment.

Comment: How is your AddressForm related to the login form? You say HOC but is the AddressForm really a wrapper around the login form or is it just that you're using the AddressForm as part of the login form?